# Java Class Library and JVM

Tags: java, jvm

I am a bit confused about JVM Architecture. Can we say that Java Class Libraries `JCL` is part of Java Virtual Machine `JVM` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-1.html#jvms-1.2),

> The Java virtual machine is an abstract computing machine ... [which]
>   knows nothing of the Java programming language.

The JCL is necessary to implement the Java language.

So you can use the JVM to implement any [language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages) of your choosing and you can run Java programs on any suitable architecture.  For example, Android can run programs written in Java on the Android Runtime (ART).

Answer (score 1):

**JVM** (Java Virtual Machine) is a part of **JRE** (Java Runtime Environment).

**JCL** (Java Library Classes) is also a part of **JRE** just like other APIs.

Answer (score 0):

According to definition JCL is libraries that Java applications (not JVM) can call at run time, I think this is rather part of JRE.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered but feel i should add some explanation to buttress some points made already:

**JVM** : executes byte code, **JCL** provides dynamically loadable runtime library which is used by java code executed by JVM.

JRE is needed at the minimum to run java program, JRE consists of JVM and JCL

**JVM** : It is an application virtual machine, with the capability to run byte code and execute it against a host operating system.

**Java** : To simple put it, Java is a high level programming language. It can be converted to byte code, which can be eventually ran on a JVM.

**Byte code** : In order to generate byte code, we need a compiler which is capable to ingesting source code and producing byte code.

**Byte code compiler** : Theoretically speaking  a byte code compiler is capable to taking any source code of most modern languages(such as python, ruby, groovy, etc) and producing byte code provided that the compiler has been implemented to do such. Another possible implementation is that the source code of a program in converted into java and then the java byte code complier is invoked to convert the generated java program into byte code, this is the case with jythonc, which takes python source code and conver it into java and then the java code is finally converted into byte code.  Example of byte code compiler is javac described above.

**In summary, the JVM is capable to running any language provided there is a compiled byte code version of the source of the language program.**

**JCL(Java class library)** : Java class library is to java programs, what operating system reusable Dll library is to native apps. It makes is possible for programs written in java to invoke operating system/hardware functions/routines which would normally be exposed by Os native libraries.  The JCL abstracts java programs from the implmentation details of the native library by providing access to native functions such as networking, io, native GUI and others.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping an eye on the language probably works best here.

A JVM is a virtual machine, so you can think of it as something that approximates a physical machine, like a laptop, desktop, or phone.  A physical machine allows you to run computer programs, and so does a virtual machine.

A JCL is a software library that helps you to run your own programs on that machine.  It is something like the libraries that exist on your physical machines that are used by your operating system and the various programs installed on that physical machine.  You have code that also makes use of the existing code provided with the machine, and together they constitute all the code needed to run a computer program on that machine.